# Promql Query - Filter on a specific string values

Tags: prometheus, promql

I would like to setup monitoring for specific info on an endpoint.
I would like to filter and create a basic response time metric for certain info on the below endpoint - "submitActivityMeasurements"

endpoint="https://dev.vitalitydeveloper.com/api/vip/manage-activities-service/1.0/svc/9998/submitActivityMeasurements/9998/26494940"